# Self retry mechanism on Failed SMS on twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am developing the application while my notification system is based on twilio platform.

I would want to know if there is the provision of SELF RETRYING on temporarily unreachable numbers (eg. 30003, 30005, 30008) while trying to send SMS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c#, the [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) library allows this type of self-retrying. I am using it to catch Twilio ApiExceptions and retry as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there is **no self retrying policy** on twilio. Raised the ticket to the official discussion center and here is the feedback.

> Hi Prabin,
>
> Thank you for contacting Twilio Support. I will be happy
> to help you with this request.
>
> I understand your question is asking
> if Twilio will retry messages on temporarily unreachable numbers.
> Twilio will not retry messages in any circumstance after the initial
> send.
>
> If you want to re-attempt messages that are undelivered, you
> will need to create the message request.   If I have misunderstood
> your question, please let me know.
>
> Regards
> Mike | Twilio Support